# update value after Ajax call PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to update TextBox value on basis of `selectChange`

HTML:

```
<select name="abc" id="def">
    <option value="1">1st Record</option>
    <option value="2">2nd Record</option>
    <option value="3">3rd Record</option>
</select>
<input value="" name="final_value" id="final_value" />
```

JS:

```
$("#selectboxid").change(function() {
  $.ajax({ url: "test.php", data:"value="+$("#def").val() , success: function(){
     $("#final_value").val(data);
  }});
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    function abc($data){
      // Database operations
      echo json_encode($response);
    }

    abc($_GET);
?>
```

With this approach value is updating very nicely But i have below points:

1. above approach prints values and one can see in Network Tab. Is it a nice way to do it?
2. I also tried using `return $response` in PHP function but then response is null and `console.log(data)` in ajax shows null array.

So, how to update Input value after Ajax without `echoing`. I do not want that user shall see any type of response even in Network Tab.

I have seen various websites which does the same and not showing any values in Network tab. 
** Is there any different approach to do this?

Comment: change like this`data:"value="+$("#def").val()`

Comment: That was a typo... changed now.. Thanks

Comment: please recheck you missed equal to symbol and hash symbol

Comment: Yup.. but let me know the concern that i have

Comment: `type:'post'` params also missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alternatively try like this

All HTTP requests can possible to watch on their own network. You can restrict this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var params = {};
    params['value'] = $("#def").val();
    $.post('test.php', params, function(response){
        console.log(response);
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not asking to change my JS... my concern is difff.. please read question

Comment: even gmail http requests can possible to watch on browser network tab. You can use https to avoid some security risks. but still this requests are visibile in the UI

Comment: Please Visit `http://www.bluestone.com/rings/the-nabha-ring~1714.html?impEvent=browseclick&posEvent=1&sortbyEvent=mostpopular&tagEvent=&ndd=false` and then try to change Ring Size... How they are changing Price of Product without showing Cost in Network tab

Comment: if you have browser tool look into the web developer tools network tab. in firefox firebug tool console and network panel. Once image is downloaded in the browser this will be catched and resused via javascript/jquery

Answer (score -1):

I've not tested this, but immediatly I've spotted a couple of things:

```
$("#selectboxid").change(function() {
    // .val is a function
  $.ajax({ url: "test.php", data:"value"+$("def").val() , success: function(data)    { //Your success callback needs to take an argument
     //data will be either a string or a JSON object, so depending on what you want from it, you'll probably not be able to just pass it to the val() function
     $("#final_value").val(data);
  }});
});
```

Not 100% complete I'm sure, but hopefully will give you a good starting point

Comment: `data:"value"+$("def").val() ` this line is not containing any error are you sure

Comment: But i do not want to echo data in PHP.. Your answer is not correct... What change have u made???

Answer (score -1):

It should be like this

```
$("#selectboxid").change(function() {
  $.ajax({ 
     url: "test.php", 
     data:{
      "value": $("def").val() 
     }, 
     success: function(){
       $("#final_value").val(data);
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the difference here to my approach with this.

Comment: you were using data:"value="+$("#def").val() and I replace that with data:{"value": $("def").val() },

Comment: Do u think that this is valid. This is totally invalid